# .htaccess mod_rewrite with language selector

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to rewrite urls such as:

```
http://www.domain.com/?language=en
http://www.domain.com/contact?language=en
```

to:

```
http://www.domain.com/en/
http://www.domain.com/en/contact
```

What I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?language=$1 [QSA,L]

http://www.domain.com/en/ <- Gives a server not found error
http://www.domain.com/en/contact <- Goes to the main root (/index.php) and give the en variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^(en|fr)(/(.*))$ $2/index.php?language=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Note:

I added `fr` in there so that you could see an example of multiple languages. Also, this will be an internal redirect to the index.php script.

Edit:

Revised to now allow for stuff after the language part of the URI. Should work how you want it now.

Here's a good reference for Regular Expressions:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Both URLs, /en/ and /en/contact, goto the root page.

Comment: Could I just hardcode all the pages:   RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*)$ /contact/index.php?language=$1 [L] or should I keep it dynamic?

Comment: No, you don't have to hard code it. I modified the rewrite rule slightly so that /en/contact will be redirected properly.

Comment: Wow thanks, I appreciate you taking the time to respond. For some reason regex is confusing to me.

Comment: You're welcome! Regex is definitely quite frustrating at times. When it works, though, it's awesome :)